# Show value from an array depending key value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've this array:

```
Array
(
    [Europa] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [AVA_Id] => 1
                    [AVA_Country] => France
                    [AVA_City] => Paris
                )
        )
    [America] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [AVA_Id] => 2
                    [AVA_Country] => Canada
                    [AVA_City] => Ottawa
                )
        )
)
```

I would like to read the 'Europa' section and get the `City` if the country is `France`.

Do you know why this code isn't working ?

```
foreach($bigArray as $key => $array) {
    $value = $array[2];
    if($bigArray[AVA_Country] == 'France')) {
        echo $bigArray['AVA_City']
    }
    else {
        echo 'No city found';        
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking `$array` in your loop, not `$bigArray`. Note you are also missing `'`s around `AVA_Country`, and there is an extra `)` in your `if` statement and a missing `;` from `echo $value['AVA_City']`. Additionally, you need to use another level of nesting to access the `AVA*` values, and there is no `$array[2]` value in your sample data so I've removed that line of code.

```
$found = false;
foreach($bigArray as $key => $array) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if($value['AVA_Country'] == 'France') {
            echo $value['AVA_City'];
            $found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) echo "No city found";
}
```

Output:

```
Paris
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/n6OCJ)

Comment: And `$array` doesn't have "2" as a key, and you never use the `$value` that you attempt to extract with that anyway...

Comment: This assumes you are iterating over the `Europe` subarray (in other words, `$bigArray` is actually Europe and not the whole array in the question)

Comment: @GregSchmidt thanks for the input, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @KodosJohnson thanks for the input, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't loop over all the deep of arrays.

```
$country = 'France';
$city = '';
$found = false;

foreach($world as $key => $continent) {
  foreach($continent as $k => $region) {
    if($region['AVA_Country'] == $country)) {
      $city = $region['AVA_City'];
      $found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if($found) break;
}
echo $city;
```